# Classifying sequence data with proper ranges

Tags: python, sequence

I've a sequence dataset and values are changing between 0 - 200 (min-max value). I'm trying to classify them with proper ranges and with integer values such as 0-1-2. For example:

```py
y_test = [0 if (i <= (max(y_test)/5)) \
          else 1 if (i > (max(y_test)/5)) & (i <= (2*max(y_test)/5)) \
          else 2 if (i > (2*max(y_test)/5)) & (i <= (3*max(y_test)/5)) \
          else 3 if (i > (3*max(y_test)/5)) & (i <= (4*max(y_test)/5)) \
          else 4 if (i > (4*max(y_test)/5)) & (i <= (5*max(y_test)/5)) \
          else 5 for i in y_test]
```

Shortly, what I want to do is:

```
class_number = 6

if y_test(i) is between 0 - (max(y_test)/class_number) --> 0
                between (max(y_test)/class_number   - (2*max(y_test)/class_number) --> 1
                between (2*max(y_test)/class_number - (3*max(y_test)/class_number) --> 2
.
.
.
```

I can use the code above for 6 different classes. But for 20 or 100 different classes?

Is there any easy way to classify the data according to max point of data?

Comment: Why is `200` hard-wired in one clause in the first line but `max(y_test)` is used everywhere else? That first line doesn't seem to mesh very well with the rest of your code, making it unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: yeap, it's forgotten there. It should be also same (max(y_test))

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try to use a more math oriented method:
`y_test = [int(i * 6 / (max(y_test)+1)) for i in y_test]`

The idea is to scale the input to 0-5 and then to round down.

EDIT: For a speed improvement you can precalculate `max(y_test)` (thanks @JohnColeman)

```py
max_val = max(y_test) + 1
y_test = [int(i * 6 / max_val) for i in y_test]
```

Comment: it's working too slow. it takes too much time to finish this process.

Comment: Reasonable answer (+1). The slowness is the result of constantly recomputing `max(y_test)`. You could improve performance by precomputing it before the comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You are really talking about [binning data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) into equal width bins. If you want to break the data into `k` bins of equal width, the width of the bins should be `w = (max - min)/k`. The bin number for a data point `x` should be the number `i` which satisfies:

```
min + i*w <= x < min + (i+1)*w
```

Hence `i = floor((x-min)/w`. A complicating fact about this approach is that the data point at the max itself will be `k` rather than `k-1`. That can be explicitly corrected for:

```
import math

def bin_nums(data,k):
    a = min(data)
    b = max(data)
    if a == b:
        return [0]*len(data)
    else:
        m = k/(b-a) #reciprocal of (b-a)/k
        return [math.floor(m*(x-a)) if x < b else k-1 for x in data]
```